# Forcing Windows 7 Compatibility mode

Tags: windows, backwards-compatibility

I'm finishing up development on a Qt/C++ program developed on Windows 7, and it seems that it only works on Windows 8 when run with Windows 7 compatibility (I'm guessing because of some WinAPI it uses). I would like this to be the default setting for the program so the user does not have to do it themselves. Is this possible?

Comment: It's probably not due to some API it uses. It's more likely due to some behavior it has that is no longer allowed on Win8. It would be better to fix the behavior so that compatibility flags were not required.

Answer (score 0):

You could try ensuring the executable manifest has the appropriate `supportedOS` values: See the Program Compatibility Assistant section in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/09/10/manifest-madness.aspx for more info.